# How to debug NSZombies & Memory Leaks?

Tags: ios, memory, nszombie

I am working on a basic game, that connects to a server and gets JSON data. It works fine for a few games, but crashes soon after due to memory pressure. I ran through instruments and came across something rather disturbing. Almost every instance variable being instantiated by [[Class alloc]init] was being leaked as a NSZombie object.

As you can see in the image, in 5 seconds I seem to have generated 9000 leaks.

I am using ARC.

Further analysis showed I was leaking when used certain methods:

```
-(void) playTimeUp
{

    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                     pathForResource:@"Gameover"
                                     ofType:@"wav"]];
    AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:nil];
    if (audioPlayer && soundShouldPlay){
        [audioPlayer setDelegate:self];
        [audioPlayer prepareToPlay];
        [audioPlayer setVolume:.20];
        [audioPlayer play];
        [self.audioPlayers addObject:audioPlayer];
    }

}
```

Also I use dataWithContentsOfUrl method quite often.

```
dispatch_async(kBackgroundQueue, ^{
        NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:completeUrl];
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(startMethod:) withObject:data   waitUntilDone:YES];

    });
```

Could anyone tell me how to salvage this situation, or what I am doing wrong.

Comment: You have `NSZombieEnabled` set to `true`? If so, as @gnasher729 said, no object gets really deallocated (they all stay in memory) so you're going to use a lot of memory very soon. You should only enable zombies to track one particular crash, and then disable them again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's in the nature of zombie objects. Turning on zombie objects to debug the use of objects after they have been deallocated will obviously turn any such object into a leak. You can't debug using zombies and search for memory leaks at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that your memory leaks will be happened due to `NSData` Object being live on memory.

Did you try to save your `NSData` to documents folder as a file instead of NSData object?

Example

```
[data writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
```

Comment: No I am not saving the the NSData. 

I disabled NSZombies, and ran the allocation in instruments, the leaks reduced drastically. However some Facebook Integration methods were leaking:

For Example when I was Posting Highscores:

Calling HTTP GET methods on FBGraphPath, it showing a leak when I read the result object.

Also my allocations showed me that VM: ImageIO_PNG_Data was 185 MB. Is this normal?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, That's an usual issue. If you are using [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"], it will be take some memory. Instead of that you should use NSCache.